# php security hole, will this fix affect my typo3

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3

[h-online](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Critical-open-hole-in-PHP-creates-risks-Update-2-1567532.html)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(%2d|-)[^=]+$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1? [L]
```

will this fix affect my typo3 (4.5) installation?

Comment: to be honest... i don't know. phpinfo says that it is installed.

Comment: run http://yourserver.com/?-s in your browser and see for yourself.

Comment: or even better, `/?+-s` in case the fix that doesn't fix the hole has been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short anwser is no. The long answer I've test it only on my installation with lighttpd + FastCGI and Typo3 4.5.5. The index.php isn't load as text file into my browser window.

Comment: thank you very much, typo3 is not affected. in fact typo runs on fastCGI and there's no such a gap

Comment: It's known, that this bug _only_ affects `php-cgi` and neither FastCGI, nor `php-fpm` (or eeven the apache module).

Comment: @derty: My installation is special because I use FastCGI. Most server has only php-cgi. You should test it again. BTW you should accept my answer because you get some points (and then you can upvote me?).